# Sequentialmodels without `input_shape` passed to the 1st layer cannot reload optimizer state

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

WARNING:tensorflow:Sequential models without an `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.

while trying to load a saved model i encountered this warning from tensorflow

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

model.save('epic_num_reader.model')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('epic_num_reader.model')
predictions = new_model.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning suggest, your first layer need the argument `input_shape`. In your case this would be the layer `Flatten`.

In the keras Documentation there is an extra section about the sequential API. See [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem after upgrading to TF 1.14, I fixed it changing the definition of the first layer from this:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
```

to this

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
```

where 28 is the size of the input map to be flattened (mnist pixels in our case)

Answer (score 0):

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(**input_shape=(28, 28)**))

for the first layer after tf 1.14 it is require to use input type which is the dimensions for the particular image.

Or you might get warning while retrieving model to not get proper working for your optimizer